# Не работает перетаскивание(draggable) с помощью мыши в слайдере jquery

Tags: html, jquery, slider

Сделал слайдер на jquery, переход между элементами по клике стрелки работает, попытался сделать возможность перетаскивания элементов мышкой, но у меня почему-то не работает. Нужно сделать без сторонних библиотек.

HTML (bootstrap 4):

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <h1 class="col-12 text-center header">Slider</h1>
            <div class="list-border">
                <ul class="row images-list">
                    <li class="images-item">
                        <img class="image" src="images/image_1.png" alt="First image">
                        <a class="next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="images-item">
                        <img class="image" src="images/image_2.png" alt="Second image">
                        <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a class="next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="images-item">
                        <img class="image" src="images/image_3.png" alt="Third image">
                        <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a class="next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="images-item">
                        <img class="image" src="images/image_4.png" alt="Fourth image">
                        <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a class="next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="images-item">
                        <img class="image" src="images/image_5.png" alt="Fifth image">
                        <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a class="next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="images-item">
                        <img class="image" src="images/image_6.png" alt="Sixth image">
                        <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a class="next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="images-item">
                        <img class="image" src="images/image_7.png" alt="Seventh image">
                        <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a class="back-to-start" href="#"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var image = $('ul li img');
    var width = image.width();

    $('ul').wrap('<div id="list-wrapper"/>');

    $('#list-wrapper').css({
        width: function () {
            return width;
        },

        height: function () {
            return image.height();
        },

        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        padding: '0'

    });

    //Get total of image sizes and set as width of ul
    var totalWidth = image.length * width;
    $('ul').css({
        width: function () {
            return totalWidth;
        }
    });

    $(image).each ( //looking for each of images in the list
        function (intIndex) {
            $(this).nextAll('a').bind("click", function () { //finding all anchors tags next to the images
                if($(this).is(".next")) {
                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (-(intIndex + 1) * width)
                    },800)
                } else if($(this).is(".previous")) {
                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (-(intIndex - 1) * width)
                    }, 800)
                    } else if ($(this).is(".back-to-start")){
                    $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                        "margin-left": (0)
                    }, 800)
                }
            });
        });

    //Mouse drag
    $(function() {
        var slides = $('#list-wrapper ul').children().length;
        var slideWidth = $('#list-wrapper').width();
        var min = 0;
        var max = -((slides - 1) * slideWidth);

        $("#list-wrapper ul").width(slides*slideWidth).draggable({
            axis: 'x',
            drag: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.position.left > min) ui.position.left = min;
                if (ui.position.left < max) ui.position.left = max;
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Перетаскивание влево-вправо?

Comment: да, сделал по примеру который нашёл здесь, но у меня не работает